# Is it possible to say "Later I didn't hear anything for a long time."?

Tags: word-choice

"We talked on the phone several times. **Later** I didn't hear anything for a long time, so I figured she didn't need my help anymore."

Can I use "later" instead of eg. "after that"? And would it be natural?

Comment: I don't think so. It sounds rather odd to me. I think the word you're looking for is ***'afterwards'***. Is this the word you want to use?

Comment: Did you make up the sentences or cite from somewhere else? [Another post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240805/109190) may need more detailed context from you.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that would be considered normal / natural.  Off hand, I'm not exactly sure why this is the case, but I think it may be that phrases like "after that" can be used to describe a period of time following some event, but "later" tends to refer only to a specific point in time in the future (not a span of time).

For this reason, you *can* use "later" if you use the *past perfect* tense (which focuses on a particular point in the past):

> Later, I had not heard anything for a long time

(at some later point in the past, it was the case that I hadn't heard anything up to then)

But the *simple past* ("didn't hear") doesn't work, because the negative simple past (when not talking about a specific event) tends to imply a period of time, not a point in time.

For the *simple past* tense, there are a few other words you can use instead of "after that" (but "later" just isn't one of them):

- then
- afterwards
- following that

You could also move "for a long time" to the front of the sentence (possibly also with "after that"/"afterward"/etc):

> For a long time, I didn't hear anything
>   For a long time after that, I didn't hear anything

Note that in all these cases, you also need a comma before the rest of the sentence ("after that, ..." / "then, ..." / etc).