# Is it grammatical to say "I didn't ... for a long time"?

Tags: tense

An [ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240800/109190) says

> We talked on the phone several times. Later **I didn't hear** anything **for a long time**, so I figured she didn't need my help anymore

which uses past simple tense with "for a long time".

Usually "for a long time" is a sign to use present perfect tense, such as

> I have studied English for a long time

So, is it grammatical to say "I didn't ... for a long time"?

Comment: when i first read the sentence , it immediately gave me the sense of "suffering a  hearing loss for a long time"

Comment: "I haven't heard from her for a long time" i think would sound right

Comment: @Moha - "I haven't heard from her for a long time" means that you still haven't. "I didn't hear from her for a long time" suggests that, eventually, the speaker did hear something from or about the other person.

Comment: oh thats a very good one to know....thank you

Comment: @KateBunting *simple past* ("didn't hear") doesn't suggest anything about what may or may not have happened later, it just says that at some previous point that was the case.  *past perfect* ("hadn't heard") does potentially have some implication that that isn't the case anymore, though (but not always).

Comment: @Foogod Well, that's how I would understand those phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use either *simple past* or *present perfect*.  They mean different things, though:

> I didn't hear anything for a long time

This is saying that *at some point in the past* you had already not heard anything for a long time (the last time you heard anything was a long time before the point in the past you're talking about now).

> I haven't heard anything for a long time

This is saying that *right now* it has been a long time since you heard anything.  This is talking about your present condition (which is why it's called the *present perfect*).

"For a long time" does not imply anything about the verb tense you should use, because it does not actually say anything about what point in time you're talking about (past/present/future).  It just says that at whatever point in time you're discussing, some condition is/was/will be true for a long duration.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. If you were the poster of the quoted sentence, would you add something like "from her"?

Comment: You certainly could add "from her", and it might help to clarify that you were specifically expecting/wanting to hear from her directly.  Since the previous sentence had just been talking about talking to her directly, however, this is already somewhat implied.