# "that's a very good one to know" vs. "that's good to know"

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts ([Is it grammatical to say "I didn't ... for a long time"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240805/109190)) a contributor says

> that's a very good one to know.

I understand that conveys the appreciation for getting to know a new use/meaning.

However, in that context I could have said

> that's good to know.

I guess both are idiomatic.

I just want to know whether the latter shows less appreciation/respect. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the situations below: 
We do know that "one" is a pronoun, but what does it refer to in the first sentences?
according to the post you linked I guess it refers to a **point**, a **trick**, **use** or something along those lines. Let's rewrite the sentences without one now:

> that's a very good point to know. (similarly - that's a good trick to know)

now which of the sentences you mentioned sounds "More appreciative" (to put it in your words)

> that's very a good point/one to know

here, one refers to point or use. and "that" refers to that explanation which was given in the article you mentioned. Therefore, this means: "the explanation in the article is a good explanation" or alternatively, "the point in the article is a good point" as you can see for yourself it reads awkwardly since we're repeating the same words twice. hence the reason why we use pronouns instead of repeating the word!

OR

> that's good to know

here though, "that" refers to the explanation or point that was mentioned in the article you linked, this essentially means, "the explanation was good"

so as you can see there is virtually little difference in meaning or strength between the two.

in other words, if you elide "very" from the first one, sentence 1 and 2 essentially convey the same level of "appreciation", meaning the element that makes sentence 1 sound more "appreciative" is "very", and it has nothing to do with "one", a measly pronoun!

Comment: Thank you. Here is some kind of supplement, the pronoun "one" refers to the use/meaning of "I didn't ... for a long time", which is exactly the topic of [that post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240805/109190)

Comment: thanks I'll edit accordingly

Comment: You do not give the citation to the dictionary or quote it. In any case, the dictionary is wrong if it asserts that "That's a good one" is restricted in use to ironic expressions of doubt or appreciation of jokes. Here is a counter-example. "Should I delete this program from the system?" "No, that is a good one." It is true that "That's a good one" is a stock phrase, but it is so only in certain social circumstances. Consequently, your correct example about the software fix explained correctly. Please edit.

Comment: Thanks @jeff I've been meaning to edit the answer myself.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly, references were added for the second part of the answer. (plus I mentioned it as a side note, not as the answer itself)

Comment: @Fermichem It's good that you have made an edit, but you have missed my point. The citations that you give are explaining a stock phrase. That stock meaning applies in certain social contexts, but other, more literal and more general, meanings apply in other contexts. Your software example is correct, but not correctly explained. I'd like to reverse my downvote because your main answer is excellent, but your sidenote confuses the issue by bringing in an irrelevancy that is not explained in a way that is entirely correct. It has already spawned a new question from the OP.

Comment: You suggest I remove it? @JeffMorrow or should I try elaborating on the side note in more depth?

Comment: All things considered, I'd remove it. It is not directly on point. It addresses a combination of words that form a stock phrase in certain contexts but not in others. Your example is correct, but your explanation is not. And it has caused confusion for the OP as shown by his next thread. Trying to fix it will be tedious and may further confuse the OP. And it all distracts from an excellent answer to the actual question.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I understand, I'll remove it, it doesn't contribute to answering the question anyways.

Comment: @Fermichem If you and the OP want to continue with me in chat, that is great. But I am busy, and my responses will be very slow. Thank you for the deletion. I have reversed my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: @JeffMorrow thanks pal :)

Comment: @JeffMorrow Your comments and answers are really helpful. Thank you, that's very kind of you. Regarding the meaning of "stock phrase" in your comments and answers, would you please explain a bit [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/241421/109190)?

Comment: A "stock phrase" is a very common way to say something in certain specific situations. It avoids thinking. "Have a nice day" is an example. Some stock phrases have become so associated with specific situations that they are almost never used any other situation, but are frequently used ironically. Other stock phrases are not so limited in their use and are thus less suitable for irony. A large part of my earlier comments was pointing out that "That's a good one" is not limited to use as a stock phrase in specific situations. I gave an example in my first comment.